# Cannot set Screenshots on test Listeners - selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pageobjects, test-framework

I am creating TestFramework and want to set in TestListener class the method which take screenshots but during failed test the Browser closes, another browser is  opened and the screenshot is created (empty screenshot).

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult){
        System.out.println(testResult.getName() + " was failure. \n Throwable " + testResult.getThrowable().getMessage());

        this.driver = DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.getBrowserTypeByProperty());
        Screenshots.captureScreenshot(driver, RandomValuesGenerator.generateRandomString(4));

        //((TestBaseClass)result.getInstance()).driver;
    }

}

public class Screenshots {

    public static void captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenShotName){
        try{
            TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
            File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("D:\\DemoQA\\ScreenShotsOfFailedTests\\" + screenShotName + ".png"));
            System.out.println("Screenshot taken " + screenShotName + ".png");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot \n" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public class DriverFactory {

    public enum BrowserType{
        FIREFOX("firefox"),
        CHROME("chrome"),
        IE("internet_explorer"),
        SAFARI("safari");

        private String value;

        BrowserType(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getBrowserName(){
            return this.value;
        }

    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver(BrowserType type){

        WebDriver driver = null;
        switch(type){
            case FIREFOX:
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D://DemoQA//drivers//geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case CHROME:
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://DemoQA//drivers//chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case IE:
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case SAFARI:
                driver = new SafariDriver();
                break;
            default:
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://DemoQA//drivers//chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public static BrowserType getBrowserTypeByProperty(){
        BrowserType type = null;
        String browserName = junitx.util.PropertyManager.getProperty("BROWSER");
        for(BrowserType bType : BrowserType.values()){
            if(bType.getBrowserName().equalsIgnoreCase(browserName)){
                type = bType;
                System.out.println("BROWSER = " + type.getBrowserName());
            }
        }
        return type;
    }

}

@Listeners(TestListener.class)
public class RegistrationTest {

    public WebDriver driver;
    RegistrationPage registrationPage;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(){
        this.driver = getDriver( DriverFactory.getBrowserTypeByProperty() );
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        registrationPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, RegistrationPage.class);
    }


    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void teardown(){
        System.out.println("AfterClass is executing ...");
        this.driver.close();
    } 

    @Test()
    public void testLoginRegistrationPage() throws Exception{
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        registrationPage.loadPage();
        registrationPage.setTextFirstNameField("Michal");
        registrationPage.clickMaritalRadioButton();
        registrationPage.tickAllCheckboxHobbies();
        registrationPage.selectCountryFromList("Poland");
        registrationPage.fillDateOfBirth("1", "10", "2014");
        registrationPage.clickSubmitButton();
        registrationPage.verifyLoggingHeader();
    }

public class RegistrationPage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(id = "name_3_firstname") WebElement firstNameField;
    @FindBy(id = "name_3_lastname") WebElement lastNameField;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value = 'married']")
......

    public RegistrationPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
        this.PAGE_TITLE = "Registration | Demoqa";
        this.PAGE_URL = "http://demoqa.com/registration/";
    }

    public void setTextFirstNameField(String text){
        setTextOnElement(firstNameField, text);
    }
     .....

}
```

The problem is in this line

```
this.driver = DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.getBrowserTypeByProperty());
```

I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the problem that the driver is recreated in the afformentioned line `this.driver = DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.getBrowserTypeByProperty());`? My hunch is that the original driver (the one running the test) should be passed to **onTestFailure** method (maybe contained in **testResult**). I'm in the dark as well a bit.

Comment: Gabor- yes I think so, but how to pass the original Driver in there ?

Comment: without the complete code of how the **testResult** is created I cannot really tell, and it is up to the maintainer of the whole framework to choose the best approach. The goal of the modifications can result in something like this: `this.driver = testResult.getDriver();` where the returning driver is the object used in the test. There are other approaches I'm sure.

Comment: I uploaded the project in here: https://uploadfiles.io/n72wj  If you have a minute take a look.

Comment: I'm behind proxy and cannot reach that site. Please seek other sources of help if you can as my own free time is usually quite limited. One last suggestion I would make is to make an extremely ugly hack first, where the original driver is saved in a static context, just to verify that the original problem was the driver re-creation.

Comment: Gabor - yes the problem is Driver re-creation I tried something like: this.driver = ((BasePage)testResult.getInstance()).driver; but get an exception: MainTests.RegistrationTest cannot be cast to Pages.BasePage. If you find the time I can send you the project on your email.

Comment: I recommend to post a new question on stackoverflow with your new findings, you will get much more response than if you ask only one guy (me).